# Identical Syntax, but one does not work. What's the difference?

Tags: php

I have two nearly identical PHP files- the first properly UPDATES the respective table and the second does not. What mistake have I committed? No errors have been thrown either. When I submit the second form, the form refreshes, however, no changes are applied to its respective table.

First Sample (Works appropriately)

```
<?php
include 'formTop.php'
;?>

    <div class="formInput">
        <p class="ph1" style="font-size: 30">Edit Current Unit</p>
        <h5 class="ph5">Edit Unit Board Form</h5>
        <hr>

    <?php

        $issue_ID = $_GET['idx'];
        $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'disolDemo');
        $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM delayboard WHERE issue_ID = '$issue_ID' LIMIT 0,1") or die($msqli->error);
        $row = $query->fetch_assoc();
        if(isset($_POST['update'])){
            $issue_ID = $_POST['issue_ID'];
            $delay_ID = $_POST['delay_ID'];
            $delayDate = $_POST['delayDate'];
            $delayTime = $_POST['delayTime'];
            $delayNote = $_POST['delayNote'];
            $result = $mysqli->query("UPDATE delayboard SET delay_ID = '$delay_ID', delayDate = '$delayDate', delayTime = '$delayTime', delayNote = '$delayNote' WHERE issue_ID='$issue_ID'");
        }
    ?>

    <div class="formInput">
    <form method='POST'>
        <div class="formAlign">
        <p class="pInput">Issue ID :</p> <input type='text' id='issue_ID' name='issue_ID' value="<?php echo $row['issue_ID']?>" readonly>
        <br/>
        <p class="pInput">Delay ID :</p> <input type='text' id='delay_ID' name='delay_ID' value="<?php echo $row['delay_ID']?>" readonly>
        <br/>
        <p class="pInput">Delay Date :</p> <input type='text' id='delayDate' name='delayDate' value="<?php echo $row['delayDate']?>" >
        <br/>
        <p class="pInput">Delay Time :</p> <input type='text' id='delayTime' name='delayTime' value="<?php echo $row['delayTime']?>" >
        <br/>           
        <p class="pInput">Delay Note :</p> <input type='text' id='delayNote' name='delayNote' value="<?php echo $row['delayNote']?>">
        <br/>
                        <input type='submit' value='update' name='update' style="margin-bottom: 25px; margin-top: -25px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
        </div>

    </form>
    </div>

<?php
include 'formBottom.php'
;?>
```

Second Sample (The one that doesn't work)

```
<?php
include 'formTop.php'
;?>

    <div class="formInput">
        <p class="ph1" style="font-size: 30">Edit Current Unit</p>
        <h5 class="ph5">Edit Unit Board Form</h5>
        <hr>

    <?php

        $issue_ID = $_GET['idx'];
        $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'disolDemo');
        $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM notesboard WHERE issue_ID = 
'$issue_ID' LIMIT 0,1") or die($msqli->error);
        $row = $query->fetch_assoc();
        if(isset($_POST['update'])){
            $issue_ID = $_POST['issue_ID'];
            $note_ID = $_POST['note_ID'];
            $noteDate = $_POST['noteDate'];
            $noteTime = $_POST['noteTime'];
            $note = $_POST['note'];
            $result = $mysqli->query("UPDATE notesboard SET note_ID = '$note_ID', noteDate = '$noteDate', noteTime = '$noteTime', note = '$note' WHERE issue_ID='$issue_ID'");
        }
    ?>

    <div class="formInput">
    <form method='POST'>
        <div class="formAlign">
        <p class="pInput">Issue ID :</p> <input type='text' id='issue_ID' name='issue_ID' value="<?php echo $row['issue_ID']?>" readonly>
        <br/>
        <p class="pInput">Note ID :</p> <input type='text' id='note_ID' name='note_ID' value="<?php echo $row['note_ID']?>" readonly>
        <br/>
        <p class="pInput">Note Date :</p> <input type='text' id='noteDate' name='noteDate' value="<?php echo $row['noteDate']?>" >
        <br/>
        <p class="pInput">Note Time :</p> <input type='text' id='noteTime' name='noteTime' value="<?php echo $row['noteTime']?>" >
        <br/>           
        <p class="pInput">Note :</p> <input type='text' id='note' name='note' value="<?php echo $row['note']?>">
        <br/>
                        <input type='submit' value='update' name='update' style="margin-bottom: 25px; margin-top: -25px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
        </div>

    </form>
    </div>


<?php
include 'formBottom.php'
;?>
```

Comment: I suggest turning on error reporting if it's not on.  These are on the same server?

Comment: Error reporting is on via error_reporting(E_ALL) - however, no errors are being thrown still.

Comment: These are on the same server, same database, different tables. The files with the syntax above are both in the same folder.

Comment: is display errors on  `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`  doesn't do any good unless you show them.

Comment: Could just be the formatting on here, but it looks like you have a ine break in your second sql query $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM notesboard WHERE issue_ID = 
'$issue_ID' LIMIT 0,1") or die($msqli->error);

Comment: Line breaks generally don't matter, I hardly ever write single line queries.

Comment: minik- yeah, that's just the formatting on the page here

Comment: ArtisticPhoenix, I applied ini_set('display_errors', 1); however, still no errors being displayed

Comment: Obviously the bits that are Not Identical are where you should be looking. The "bits" appear to be your SQL Statements... So I'd be echoing those and seeing if they make sense. Even trying them out directly in your favorite mysql interface like phpmyadmin or similar.

Comment: this is confusing `$issue_ID = $_GET['idx'];` and `$issue_ID = $_POST['issue_ID'];` not saying it's wrong, but confusing.  Oh and use Prepared statements, to prevent the SQL vulnerabilities you have in your code.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the time, but I've located my mistake- I should be selecting rows by my unique primary key, which in the cases above is display_ID and note_ID. Instead I'm editing based off my issue_ID selection and there are entries with duplicate issue_ID's (my foreign key). I should have done this from the start. Since there are duplicate issue_ID's, changes were not being applied to the table.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for the time, but I've located my mistake- I should be selecting rows by my unique primary key, which in the cases above is display_ID and note_ID. Instead I'm editing based off my issue_ID selection and there are entries with duplicate issue_ID's (my foreign key). I should have done this from the start. Since there are duplicate issue_ID's, changes were not being applied to the table.